# Write log when somebody attempt to load OS

Tags: linux, permissions, login, logging, arch-linux

I'd like to write a log when somebody attempt to access my computer. (e.g. enter login and password, doesn't matter successfully or not).
I use Arch Linux and CDM (console display manager).

ps: I have very strong suspicions that someone really do it, and at least, I'd like to know  what time it happen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The log should already exist. Try using the `last` command.

Login failures are normally logged by syslog to somewhere like `/var/log/messages` You can grep that file for login failures.